# pgsql: select data at time zone in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to run the following statement in PHP:

`SELECT ((somedate at time zone 'utc') at time zone 'cet') FROM sometable;`

But i only get this error Message:

`Notice: Undefined index: somedate in /var/www/html/foo.php on line 1337`

If i run the same statement in pgAdmin it works fine.
Database is Postgres, PHP driver is php-pgsql on PHP7.0.

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Hi. Please include the PHP code being used to run the SQL statement so that we can assist. Thanks!

Comment: And the definition of `sometable`.

Comment: The statement was changing the of `somedate` to `?column?`. Thanks for responses :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it: you need to add `as somedate` when you run the query from PHP!

`SELECT ((somedate at time zone 'utc') at time zone 'cet') as somedate FROM sometable;` worked for me.